# Banned from Admob! Rewarded Video?

Tags: video, admob

I was recently banned from Admob. The only thing I use to monetize my app are rewarded videos. My app has only a few users and I make roughly 10$ a month.

The formally reason of banning:

*"We found instances of one or more users clicking repeatedly on AdMob ads within your apps, which is prohibited by the AdSense Program Policies"*

So, is there an upper limit of how many rewarded videos one is allowed to watch?? And if so, where can I find the terms for it?

From my current point of view I have no idea whats wrong with my usage of admob.

Answer (score 0):

Admob's terms and conditions can be found at https://developers.google.com/admob/terms

There is no upper limit on how many rewarded videoes one is allowed to watch, however there are very strict rules in regards to invalid activity.

The relavant part for you:

> **5. Payment**
>
> ...
>
> Invalid activity includes, but is not limited to
>
> (i) spam, invalid clicks, invalid impressions, invalid queries, invalid conversions, or other invalid events on Ads generated by any person, bot, automated program or similar device, including through any clicks, impressions, queries, conversions, or other events originating from your IP addresses or computers under your control;
>
> (ii) clicks, impressions, queries, conversions, or other events solicited or generated by payment of money, false representation, or requests for end users to click on Ads or take other actions;
>
> (iii) Ads served to end users whose browsers have JavaScript disabled or who are otherwise tampering with ad serving or measurement;
>
> (iv) any click, impression, query, conversion, or other event occurring on a Property that does not comply with the AdSense Policies;
>
> (v) any click, impression, query, conversion, or other event occurring on a Property associated with another AdSense Account you use; and
>
> (vi) all clicks, impressions, queries, conversions, or other events in any Account with significant amounts of invalid activity, as described in (i-v) above or with the types of invalid activity indicating intentional misconduct. In the event Google detects invalid activity, either before or after issuing a payment for that activity, Google reserves the right to debit your Account, and adjust future payments accordingly, for all invalid clicks, impressions, queries, conversions, or other events including for all clicks, impressions, queries, conversions, or other events on Properties that do not comply with the AdSense Policies.